# url rewriting is not working in k8s on eks

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am trying to make rewrite url in eks. I aim to tranform /foo url i n /.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: granada-urls
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $1
    # Ingress Core Settings
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
spec:
 rules:
 - host: 
   http:
     paths: 
     - path: /foo
       backend:
         serviceName: frontend-svc
         servicePort: 80
```

When I call the url (, this rewrite process does not work correctly and I get these error at the nginx logs

```
172.31.14.191 - - [11/Feb/2021:13:26:51 +0000] "GET /foo HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" "XXXXXXX"
2021/02/11 13:26:51 [error] 29#29: *912 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/foo" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.31.14.191, server: localhost, request: "GET /foo HTTP/1.1", host: "XXXXXXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Hello, please try to change the annotation from: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"` to `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` and tell if it helped.I don't think you'll need to have `alb.ingress.XXX` annotations in this `Ingress` manifest. Also please change the rewrite to: `/$2` and the path to: `/foo(/|$)(.*)`

Comment: unfortunnaltly, when I change in eks ingress class from alb to nginx, no more LB is created

Comment: How have you deployed your `Nginx Ingress` controller? Do you have the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` associated with the `Pod` of your controller ( `$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx)`?

Comment: `NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-ingress-6bb85cf7d9-cm78x   1/1     Running   0          11d

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-ingress   1/1     1            1           11d

NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-6bb85cf7d9   1         1         1       11d
`

Comment: @DawidKruk : yes I exposed the deployement as LB

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the changes you've made that you are still experiencing issues with. Also, which guide how you used to provisioned your `nginx-ingress`? Can you see the reload in the `nginx-ingress` logs?